# Recursive expression of iota

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I was playing around with iota in my Math lecture today and I observed something very, very strange.

We can write a complex number z, in polar form as

$$
z = r e^{\iota\theta}
$$

where e is the base of the natural logarithm.

So, going in the same fashion, we can also express iota itself in this form, as

$$
i = e^{\iota\pi/2}
$$

And then we have the expression of iota that itself equals to the power of the base of the natural logarithm (multiplied by  pi/2)

So I wanted to ask if this recurrence (or dependency, pardon me I couldn't really get the right word for it), is just a mere coincidence, or has some mathematical implications as well? Because this recurrence implies that we can express the complex number z

$$
z = re^{\iota\theta}
$$

as

$$
z = re^{e^{\iota\pi/2}\theta}
$$

And in the similar manner, as

$$
z = re^{e^{e^{\iota\pi/2}\pi/2}\theta}
$$

And so on.

So does this recursive plugging of the value of iotas really have any implications or consequences, or any meaning perhaps?

Thankyou.

Comment: This does not define $i$, and in fact it doesn't even characterize it, as we also have $-i = e^{-i \cdot \pi / 2}$ (this latter problem isn't such an issue, as it does characterize $i$ up the action of the automorphisms of $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb R$, i.e., up to conjugation).

Comment: @Travis Is the word expression correct over the word 'definition'? I have edited the question as per your answer that it does not define 'i' (maybe expression is the word over 'definition')?

Comment: I might just simply say, "$i$ satisfies the equation...".